# How do I install packages selectively from repositories?

Tags: repository, updates

In my case I've got lucid installed on my server but want to install a newer saned version.

There is one in the maverick and lucid repositories, how would I add this repository for just *that one package*?

What should I look for when doing this?

Comment: So you want to install a single package from maverick repos, having a lucid installation, is it correct?

Comment: @enzotib: Yes, that's correct. The reason I want to use the repository is that this allows me to update the software easily.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't mix packages from different releases. It may work in some cases when the dependency changes do not have an impact on the package upgrade.

Your options are to either find a ppa which provides an updated version for your release, or rebuild the package yourself from the latest source, you can find how to do this at:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by *when the dependency changes do not have an impact on the package upgrade*? If I install a package from maverick in lucid that has few dependencies, shouldn't it be possible to upgrade only those? (Of course this is a problem if the dependency tree is too big.)

Comment: Updating the "few" dependencies for the package you need will force you to upgrade all the dependent packages which you dont want. You answered yourself, the dependency tree is too deep, you are likely to get into broken dependencies.